# Tailwindcss manual dark mode doesn't work in NextJS project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I need to integrate the dark mode into my project. I use ***NextJs v12.1.3***, ***react 18.1.0*** and ***tailwindcss v3.1.2***. I tried [this guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode) on the official site, but the manual selection doesn't work for me. It always shows the operating system's theme.

For example if I want to force the theme to be light I do this:

```
    <html className="light">
      <body className="h-10 w-10">
        <div className="bg-white flex w-10 h-10 dark:bg-black"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This shows always the OS' theme. I also added this to force it:

```js
    // On page load or when changing themes, best to add inline in `head` to avoid FOUC
    if (
      localStorage.theme === 'dark' ||
      (!('theme' in localStorage) &&
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)
    ) {
      document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
    }
    
    // Whenever the user explicitly chooses light mode
    localStorage.theme = 'light';
```

I also did this into the `_document.tsx` file:

```json
    <Html className="light">
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
```

I also set up `darkMode: 'class'` into the `tailwind.config.js` file

This is my full *`tailwind.config.js`* file

```json
    const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

    module.exports = {
      purge: [],
      darkMode: 'class',
      content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
      ],
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
      theme: {
        colors: {
          transparent: 'transparent',
          current: 'currentColor',
          black: '#212121',
          white: colors.white,
          gray: {
            ...colors.gray,
            100: '#f0f2f5',
            200: '#DADFE7',
            300: '#a9b5c6',
            400: '#6c809d',
            500: '#647697',
            600: '#5a6C87',
            700: '#394556',
            800: '#313B49',
            900: '#181D25',
          },
          teal: {
            50: '#ECFDFA',
            100: '#DAFCF6',
            200: '#B4F8ED',
            300: '#8FF5E4',
            400: '#6AF1DB',
            500: '#47EED1',
            600: '#15E0BE',
            700: '#10A88F',
            800: '#0A705F',
            900: '#053830',
          },
          indigo: colors.indigo,
          red: colors.rose,
          yellow: colors.amber,
          orange: {
            ...colors.orange,
            300: '#ffce30',
            700: '#d49100',
          },
          extend: {
            transitionDuration: {
              0: '0ms',
              2000: '2000ms',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
    };
```

To be honest, I want only light mode at this moment, but I have some components styled also for dark mode and I don't want to restyle them because later I will need it.

What do you think I did wrong?

P.S. *I don't want to use `next-themes` to handle the dark/light mode.*

Comment: Can you add your full `tailwind.config.js` file to the question?

Comment: I have just done it! @EdLucas

Comment: What do you actually want ? you are saying manual dark mode is not working in the question, but at the end you are saying you want only the light mode, Which mode do you want? And how do you want ? you want to force dark / light mode ? or leave it to system option ?

Comment: If I say I need light mode only, it means that it cannot be automatic. Yes I need to force light mode, In fact I wrote : "To be honest, I want only light mode at this moment, but I have some components styled also for dark mode and I don't want to restyle them because later I will need it.". If it has to be forced it means also that it has to be set manually. It would not be dynamic, all right but it is not automatic.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `tailwind.config.js` is configured with `darkMode: 'class'`, make sure that when you wrap the app in the ThemeProvider you use:

```html
<ThemeProvider attribute="class">
```

That will tell `next-themes` to use `light/dark` classes on the main `<HTML>` tag.

Source: https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes#class-instead-of-data-attribute

Answer (score 1):

For Manual dark mode , do the following :

In `tailwind.config.css` set the `darkMode` to `class`

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  // ...
}
```

And when you need the `darkMode` just add `ClassName` of `dark` inside the `html` tag

```
<html className="dark">
<body>
  <!-- Will be black -->
  <div className="bg-white dark:bg-black">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And when you need the `light` just remove `ClassName` of `dark` inside the `html` tag

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use from

> next-themes

or

> use-dark-mode

To manage dark mode it will add `.dark-theme` class but tailwind need `.dark`

What is the **solution** now?

Add the following code to `tailwind.config.js` file

```
darkMode: ['class','.dark-theme']
```